# Print the memory address of a local constant variable

Tags: swift, function, memory-address

I have a very simple customer class type named **Dog** which only contains a string typed variable. A function which can changes the value of the instance of the **Dog** type is defined as follow.

**Question:**

***d*** is the local variable defined within the function, I've tried the withUnsafePointer, seem it needs the inout parameter or at least a mutable variable (var), I would like to know if there is a way to print out the memory address of the local variable ***d*** ?

```
class Dog {
    var name: String = "Fido"
}

func dogChanger(_ d: Dog) {
    d.name = "Rover"
    withUnsafePointer(&d) { NSLog("\($0)") } //d needs to be a inout parameter 
}
```

Thanks for your time and help

Comment: Try `let dog = d` and then use `dog`.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, since this is an instance of a class, assigning a `var` variable to this instance `d` of `Dog` will not copy it so any changes you make to that pointer will be reflected in the initial. Observe the following:

```
class Dog {
    var name: String = "Fido"
}

func dogChanger(_ d: Dog) {
    d.name = "Rover"
    var x = d
    // 1
    print(d.name)
    x.name = "Changed1"
    // 2
    print(d.name)
    withUnsafePointer(to: &x) {
        $0.pointee.name = "Changed2";
        // 3
        print("\($0)")
    }

    // 4
    print(d.name)
}


var d = Dog()
dogChanger(d)
//5
print(d.name)
```

On my machine this outputs the following:

```
Rover
Changed1
0x00007fff5dd49200
Changed2
Changed2
```

As you can see, at print statement 1 we logged the name after changing it directly on `d`. At the second one we saw that the name of `d` was changed when we changed the name of the variable `x`. At the third statement we get the address of `x`. At the fourth we see that changing the name of the object pointed to by `x` changed the name of `d` and finally in the last statement we see that the `Dog` instance we passed in successfully had its final name changed this way. This tells us that `d` and `x` point to the same object.

Keep in mind; though, that this class instance is only guaranteed to exist for the execution of your `dogChanger` function so do not allow that pointer to escape the function.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I believe I didn't explain my problem in a good way. By creating a **x** (var), it creates a new memory block in the stack, in conjunction with the previous one, i.e **d** (let), 2 of the stack blocks contain the same "pointer" which reference to the same object in the heap, but the 2 stack-blocks have their own stack address.  I think 0x00007fff5dd49200 is the stack address of the **x**, but I'm interested in the stack address of **d**,  would this be possible to print inside the function? Thanks again.